# Combine np.equal and np.less to create single dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, outer-join

I have the following:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Effective_Date':pd.to_datetime(['12/31/2017', '1/31/2018', '2/28/2018', '3/31/2018', '9/30/2020']),
                'Amount':[100,150,300,500,750]})


Date_Range = pd.date_range('12/31/2017', periods=150, freq='M')
```

I'm trying to create a single dataframe that returns df1['Amount'] when the month of df1['Effective_Date'] = the month of Date_Range. However, if the Date_Range is < df1['Effective_Date'], return 0.

For example, an effective date of 1/31/19 with Amount = 5 would have 5 for Date_Range = 1/31/19, 1/31/20, 1/31/21, etc. and 0s everywhere else.

I can do the two pieces separately:

If months are equal:

```
df2 = (pd.DataFrame(np.equal.outer(df1.Effective_Date.dt.month, Date_Range.month) * df1.Amount.values[:,None], columns = Date_Range))
```

If Date_Range < Effective Date, return 0:

```
df3 = (pd.DataFrame(np.less_equal.outer(df1.Effective_Date, Date_Range) * df1['Amount'].values[:,None], columns = Date_Range))
```

But I'm not sure how to combine the two. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: Sorry about that, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I beleive you need [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
a = np.equal.outer(df1.Effective_Date.dt.month, Date_Range.month) * df1.Amount.values[:,None]
b = np.less_equal.outer(df1.Effective_Date, Date_Range) * df1['Amount'].values[:,None]

m =  Date_Range.values < df1['Effective_Date'].values[:,None]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(m, a, b), columns = Date_Range)
print (df)
   2017-12-31  2018-01-31  2018-02-28  2018-03-31  2018-04-30  2018-05-31  \
0         100         100         100         100         100         100   
1           0         150         150         150         150         150   
2           0           0         300         300         300         300   
3           0           0           0         500         500         500   
4           0           0           0           0           0           0   

     2029-12-31  2030-01-31  2030-02-28  2030-03-31  2030-04-30  \
0     ...             100         100         100         100         100   
1     ...             150         150         150         150         150   
2     ...             300         300         300         300         300   
3     ...             500         500         500         500         500   
4     ...             750         750         750         750         750   

   2030-05-31  
0         100  
1         150  
2         300  
3         500  
4         750  

[5 rows x 150 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael. I think it's close but there are a few things off: 1) Series 'a' doesn't seem to be working anymore. I'd expect an effective date of 1/15/19 to show an amount only in January so 1/31/19, 1/31/20, 1/31/21, etc. Also, effective date 9/30/20 appears to have values start all the way back at 9/30/18 but I would expect 0s until 9/30/20.

Comment: @EChan - Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? Not easy testing (maybe 1-2 months data only)